# Global variable not working in php when using new ReflectMethod

Tags: php, php-5.4

I am facing some errors with use of global variables.
I defined a $var in global scope and trying to use it in functions but it not accessible there. Please see below code for better explanation:

File a.php:

```
<?php

  $tmp = "testing";

  function testFunction(){
     global $tmp;
     echo($tmp);
  }
```

So a bit about how this function is called.

File b.php:

```
<?php
  include 'a.php'
  class testClass{
    public function testFunctionCall(){
        testFunction();
    }
  }
```

The above 'b.php' is called using:

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod($this, $method);
$method->invoke();
```

Now the desired output is 'testing' but the output received is NULL.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have a feeling that this has something to do with the use of the ReflectionMethod but i cant understand the reason as to why it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. **[TESTED]**. Also , what is stopping you from using call by reference ?

```
<?php
$tmp = "testing";

function testFunction(){
global $tmp;
echo($tmp);
}

class testClass
{
      public function testFunctionCall(){
          testFunction();
      }
}

$method = new ReflectionMethod($this, $method);
$method->testFunctionCall();
```